# Creating a view that shows tiles as the user types

Tags: ios, ios6, uiview, uicollectionview, uistoryboard

I am looking to create a View Controller used for a user to select a word. The user chooses the word by typing in the word.

What I am looking for is the best approach to achieve the following:
When the VC loads the keyboard will show. As the user types each letter a new tile is shown above the keyboard, building as each letter is typed.

What is the best way to achieve this, with a `UICollectionView` or custom `UIView`. With either route, what would be the best way to set this up in a `Storyboard`? Also how would I add each sub view every time a letter is typed next to the previous?
Further to this, I would need to scale down these views dependant on the amount of letters typed, where should this be completed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you want to create a `UICollectionViewCell` with a single letter within it each time a user types a letter? How are you wiring the keyboard to this functionality? If you are using a UITextField you can register as it's delegate and insert your cells when the delegate method `textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:` is called.

As far as the layout issues and scaling things based on how many letters are on screen, take a look at the "[Best Practices for Mastering Auto Layout](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/?id=228)" session. There is actually a demonstration fairly similar to what you are trying to achieve in there with letters. Assuming I understand what you are trying to do.